# fix TD div positioning inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Inside my Table A cell(TD) is having customized drop down . 
My Problem is that once drop down appears instead of drop down coming above table scroll appears in the table but i want customized drop down should appear above below cells .I think the issues is related to css : position  but i m unable to do that

I am using the following code

```
  <div class="tablecontainer table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="results" 
     style="width:100%;">
   <tr>

<th><b>Student Level </b></th>
<th><b>Marks Value</b></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>
<div class="dropdownlist" id="dropdownprodlevel" style="position:fixed;">
     <a>PAL1</a>

    <a>PAL2</a>

    <a>PAL3</a>

    <a>PAL4</a>

    <a>DEVICE</a>
   </td>
  <td>Cell2</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, your `dropdownlist` is not closed etc. Please provide minimal code to reproduce the issue. You can start with [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfns6kwy/).

Comment: Also I feel posting any CSS used here would be very useful, so yes, provide a minimal and complete example, with more than just some unfinished HTML.